# Sql query for 3 tables checks either of table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having 3 tables 
1 : Employee
2 : Department
3 : Experts

I want the experts which belong to CmpId = 1

Employee :

```
id  CmpId 
1   2   
2   1   
3   1
```

Department

```
id  CmpId 
1   1   
2   2   
3   2
```

Experts :

```
id  EmployeeId DepartmentId 
1   1          2
2   2          null
3   null       1
4   2          1
5   null       null
```

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? mysql/sql-server and postgresql are very different.

Comment: What are the results for your sample data?

Comment: which CmpId  we need to use ?

Comment: @Jens : using sql-server. I know all are diff but queries can transform to any.                                                                                            Gordon Linoff : Result would be Expert with id 2,3,4                       Navjot Singh : First i have to consider Employee if it is null then only i have to consider Department

Answer (score 1):

INNER JOIN the three tables

If they need to be CmpId = 1 in BOTH (this returns nothing in your sample data but assuming it is a larger data set)

```
SELECT e.id, e.EmployeeId, e.DepartmentId
FROM Experts e
FULL OUTER JOIN Department d ON e.DepartmentId = d.id
FULL OUTER JOIN Employee em ON e.EmployeeId = em.id
WHERE d.CmpId = 1 AND em.CmpId = 1
```

If they need to be CmpId = 1 in Either

```
SELECT e.id, e.EmployeeId, e.DepartmentId
FROM Experts e
FULL OUTER JOIN Department d ON e.DepartmentId = d.id
FULL OUTER JOIN Employee em ON e.EmployeeId = em.id
WHERE d.CmpId = 1 OR em.CmpId = 1
```

Comment: I think you didn't get my issue. You are taking inner join , if some some expert.deptId contain null then the join will give null

Comment: @HemantMalpote Just use full outer for this then. Answer updated

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess that `NULL` in the `expert` table means that someone is an expert for all departments.  If so:

```
select e.employeeid
from experts e join
     departments d
     on e.departmentid = d.id or e.departmentid is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, the desired results based on the sample data should be Expert ID's 2,3 and 4.

Expert ID 2 has an Employee ID of 2, which has a CmpID of 1. 
Expert ID 3 has a Department ID of 1, which has a CmpID of 1.
Expert ID 4 has an Employee ID of 2, which has a CmpID of 1 and a Department ID of 1 which has a CmpID of 1.

If this is in fact the desired result set, I would write the following query.

```
SELECT ex.id, ex.EmployeeID, ex.DepartmentID
  FROM @Experts ex
  LEFT JOIN @Department dep
    ON ex.DepartmentID = dep.id
  LEFT JOIN @Employee emp
    ON ex.EmployeeID = emp.id
 WHERE dep.CmpID = 1 OR emp.CmpID = 1
```

That will yield the following results.

```
id  EmployeeID  DepartmentID
2   2           NULL
3   NULL        1
4   2           1
```